# Replace characters except the last 4 characters with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project and wanted to replace characters except the last 4 characters with javascript. Need a little help, Thanks

```
 var string = $('div.reg-summary-rows:nth-child(5) p:nth-child(2) span.reg-summary-answers').innerHTML;
 var len = string.length;
 var sub = len - 4;
 var string2 = "*****"
 var newString = string.slice(sub); 
document.querySelector("div.reg-summary-rows:nth-child(5) p:nth-child(2) span.reg-summary-answers").innerHTML = string2 ;
```

Comment: Maybe `"*".repeat(string.length - 4) + string.slice(-4)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```js
const foo = '1234567890';
const limit = 4;
const head = foo.slice(0, -limit);
const tail = foo.slice(-limit);

console.log(head.replace(/./g, '*') + tail);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) of [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) this way:

```js
const replaceAllExceptLast = (str, n) =>
{
    let token = "*";

    return str.replace(/./g, (match, offset) =>
    {
        return offset < str.length - n ?  token : match;
    });
}

console.log(replaceAllExceptLast("Hello World", 1));
console.log(replaceAllExceptLast("Hello World", 4));
console.log(replaceAllExceptLast("Hello World", 7));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note, the regular expression will match every character, but we only going to do a replacement if the `offset` of the matched element satisfy the condition.